# IronPython NAudio Looping Crossfade Glitch

Tags: ironpython, naudio, cross-fade

I am using NAudio within IronPython to mix several audio streams to create ambient audio. This works reasonably well for some tracks, but for some others (wind, rain) it can have a jarring stop/start on looping playback.

Because I wasn't 100% sure how to implement LoopStream class example in python originally, I had started out simply having a position check after a tenth of a second or less. I know why I had gaps there.  Since then, I was able to figure out how to re-create LoopStream in python, and it works, but I still had the gap in playback as before.  I am trying to cross-fade the end of the track into the beginning of the same track now, and when I do that the audio glitches out entirely.
Here's the code:

```
class LoopStream(WaveStream):
  def __init__(self,WaveStream,AudioStream):
    self.wavestream = WaveStream
    self.audiostream = AudioStream    
  def get_WaveFormat(self):
    return self.wavestream.WaveFormat
  def get_Length(self):
    return self.wavestream.Length
  def get_Position(self):
    return self.wavestream.Position
  def HasData(count):
    return True

  def Read(self,buf,offset,count):    
    read = 0
    while(read < count):            
      required = count - read
      #print(str(self.audiostream.get_chan_id()) + " reading @ " + str(self.wavestream.Position) + "/" + str(self.wavestream.Length))
      pos = self.wavestream.Position
      readthistime = self.wavestream.Read(buf,offset+read,required)
      if pos == 0:
        self.startbuf = buf      
      if readthistime < required:
        self.wavestream.Position = 0
        #print(len(buf))
        #buf = buf+self.startbuf               
        print(len(buf))
        buf = FadeOut(self,buf,offset,readthistime) + FadeIn(self,self.startbuf,0,required)
        print(len(buf))
        readthistime+=required
        print(str(self.audiostream.get_chan_id()) + " restarting1")
      elif self.wavestream.Position + required > self.wavestream.Length:        
        #read += readthistime
        #readthistime = self.wavestream.Read(buf,self.wavestream.Position,required)
        #print(str(self.audiostream.get_chan_id()) + " restarting2")
        pass
      if self.wavestream.Position >= self.wavestream.Length:
        self.wavestream.Position = 0 
        buf = buf + self.startbuf 
        print(str(self.audiostream.get_chan_id()) + " restarting3")
      read += readthistime
    return read

  def FadeOut(self,buf,offset,count):
    sample = 0
    maxfadesamples = int((self.wavestream.WaveFormat.SampleRate * 75) / 1000)
    fadesamples = 0 
    while sample < count:
      multiplier = 1.0 - (fadesamples / maxfadesamples)
      for i in range(0,self.wavestream.WaveFormat.Channels):       
        buf[offset+sample] *= multiplier
        sample+=1
      fadesamples+=1

      if fadesamples > maxfadesamples:
        for j in range(0,self.wavestream.WaveFormat.Channels):
          while sample < count:
            buf[offset+sample] = 0 
            sample+=1
  def FadeOut(self,buf,offset,count):
    sample = 0    
    maxfadesamples = int((self.wavestream.WaveFormat.SampleRate * 75) / 1000)
    fadesamples = 0 
    while sample < count:
      multiplier = (fadesamples / maxfadesamples)
      for i in range(0,self.wavestream.WaveFormat.Channels):
        buf[offset+sample] *= multiplier
        sample+=1
      fadesamples+=1
```

Comment: Err .. already noticing I just need to get used to adding error handling statements here .. because I noticed a few problems immediately after posting, so I may end up solving myself 1) FadeOut is declared twice, so FadeIn isn't actually there at all.  Once I did rename FadeOut #2 to FadeIn, it was still having the glitch but because it was stuck in an infinite loop.  I fixed that and still having the problem but I think it's erroring out somewhere else in read function.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking stupid question.... should have been obvious that the functions I was using weren't returning a buffer but were just acting on a buffer passed to them.

So solution was easily determined once I got a good error message

This line:

```
buf = FadeOut(self,buf,offset,readthistime) + FadeIn(self,self.startbuf,0,required)
```

Became:

```
try:
  self.FadeOut(buf,offset,readthistime) 
  self.FadeIn(self.startbuf,0,required)
  buf = buf = self.startbuf
except Exception, e:
  print(repr(e))
```

So the problem was I was trying to add the "resulting buffer" from 2 procedures that have no result, and I just needed to run them and then do the adding. The cross-fade makes the gap significantly less noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a much better solution than my previous attempt, this one cross-fades instead of doing a fade-in/fade-out, which did minimize the gap but it was still a noticeable glitch on restart for some tracks.

```
class LoopStream(WaveStream):
  def __init__(self,WaveStream,AudioStream):   
    self.wavestream = WaveStream
    self.originalstream = self.wavestream
    self.audiostream = AudioStream

    if (float(self.get_Length()) / self.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond) > 6:
      self.CFSeconds = 3.1
    else:
      #self.CFSeconds = (self.LSeconds / 2.0) + 0.1
      self.CFSeconds = ((float(self.get_Length()) / self.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond)/2) - 0.1
    self.CFBytes = int(round(self.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond*self.CFSeconds))
    #determine bytes per section of audio
    temp = (self.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8) * self.WaveFormat.Channels
    #determine how many bytes we are over target
    temp = self.CFBytes % temp
    #subtract bits to get to target 
    self.CFBytes-=temp

    self.startbuf = Array.CreateInstance(System.Byte,self.CFBytes)
    self.endbuf = Array.CreateInstance(System.Byte,self.CFBytes)
    self.wavestream.Read(self.startbuf,0,self.CFBytes)
    self.wavestream.Position = self.Length - self.CFBytes
    self.wavestream.Read(self.endbuf,0,self.CFBytes)

    self.wavestream.Position = 0 

    #self.startbuf = self.buf[:int(round(self.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond*CFSeconds))]        
    self.FadeIn(self.startbuf,0,int(round(self.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond*self.CFSeconds)))    

    #self.endbuf = self.buf[self.Length-int(round(self.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond*CFSeconds)):]
    self.FadeOut(self.endbuf,0,int(round(self.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond*self.CFSeconds)))
    self.FirstPlay = True 

    self.startstream = RawSourceWaveStream(self.startbuf,0,self.CFBytes,self.WaveFormat)
    self.endstream = RawSourceWaveStream(self.endbuf,0,self.CFBytes,self.WaveFormat)
    self.crossfadestream = MixingWaveProvider32() #self.startstream,self.endstream)
    self.crossposition = 0 
    self.crossfadestream.AddInputStream(self.startstream)
    self.crossfadestream.AddInputStream(self.endstream)
    self.CFBuffer = Array.CreateInstance(System.Byte,self.CFBytes)
    self.crossfadestream.Read(self.CFBuffer,0,self.CFBytes)

    print(self.audiostream.chan_id,"initialized")
  def get_WaveFormat(self):
    return self.wavestream.WaveFormat
  def get_Length(self):
    return self.wavestream.Length
  def get_Position(self):
    return self.wavestream.Position
  def HasData(count):
    return True
  def LSeconds(self):
    return float(self.get_Length()) / self.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond 
  def PSeconds(self):
    return float(self.get_Position()) / self.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond
  def Read(self,buf,offset,count):    
    read = 0
    while(read < count):            
      required = count - read
      readthistime = 0 
      if self.FirstPlay == True:
        if (int(self.Position) + read >= self.CFBytes) or (int(self.Position) + read >= int(self.Length) - self.CFBytes):
          self.FirstPlay = False

      if self.FirstPlay == True or ((int(self.Position) + read) < (int(self.Length) - self.CFBytes) and (int(self.Position) + read > self.CFBytes)):                
        try:
          #print(self.audiostream.chan_id,"Normal")
          readthistime = self.wavestream.Read(buf,offset+read,required)          
        except Exception, e:
          exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
          fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
          print(exc_type,fname,exc_tb.tb_lineno)
      else:       
        try:        
          #print(self.audiostream.chan_id,"Crossfade")
          buf = self.CFBuffer
          self.wavestream.Position = self.CFBytes + ((self.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample/8)*self.WaveFormat.Channels)
          read += self.CFBytes          
          return read
        except Exception, e:
          exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
          fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
          print(exc_type,fname,exc_tb.tb_lineno)
      read += readthistime
    return read

  def FadeOut(self,buf,offset,count):    
    sample = 0
    maxfadesamples = int((self.WaveFormat.SampleRate * self.CFSeconds))
    fadesamples = 0 
    while sample < count:
      multiplier = 1.0 - (fadesamples / maxfadesamples)
      for i in range(0,self.wavestream.WaveFormat.Channels):       
        try:          
          buf[offset+sample] *= multiplier        
        except Exception, e:
          exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
          fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
          print(sample,exc_type,fname,exc_tb.tb_lineno)
          return
        sample+=1
      fadesamples+=1

      if fadesamples > maxfadesamples:        
        while sample < count:          
          buf[offset+sample] = 0           
          sample+=1
        break
  def FadeIn(self,buf,offset,count):    
    sample = 0    
    maxfadesamples = int((self.WaveFormat.SampleRate * self.CFSeconds))
    fadesamples = 0 
    while sample < count:    
      multiplier = (fadesamples / maxfadesamples)
      for i in range(0,self.wavestream.WaveFormat.Channels):
        buf[offset+sample] *= multiplier
        sample+=1
      fadesamples+=1
      if fadesamples>maxfadesamples:
        break
```